# Web application safari full screen bottom nav fixed not working

Tags: html, css, ios, web-applications, safari

When I'm running my website on an `iPhone X(R,S, 11)` my mobile footer nav is not fixed to the bottom and I have set the position to fixed and to bottom: 0px. **I added the meta tag viewport-fit=cover, but it isn't working. Can somebody help me out?**

```
.mobile-bottom-nav {
    position: fixed;
    position: -ms-device-fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -35px;
    left: 0px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: saturate(200%) blur(20px);
    backdrop-filter: saturate(180%) blur(20px);
    border-top: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Meta tag below:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover, user-scalable=no">
```

Picture of my web application:
It shows a empty bar under the bottom nav.

[[image]]

Comment: Possibly something to do with the -35px margin? I would need working code to debug.

Comment: No if I remove that it is still the same

Comment: If I remove the meta tag with viewport-fit=cover then it is at the bottom again, but then the status bar is empty instead of blue